# apache 2 WEB_DOCUMENT_ROOT not correct, error logs shows "Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/"

Tags: apache2, virtualhost

this is a bit weird, it is not the first time (and sure not the last) I am working with apache2 in a docker cotainer.
I've a look to the config **apache2.conf** and it looks fine to me:

```
<Directory />
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I also add an "**000-default.conf**" file to the sites-available:
*/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf*

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/webroot

    <Directory /var/www/html/webroot>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I also tried to add the webroot folder path to this apache2.conf, but it still not working:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/webroot>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

My project files (index.php also) are located in /var/www/html/webroot path, but the brower shows a **403 error** :"You don't have permission to access this resource."

I also checked the apache logs, and I found this.... It is very weird because I never setup this folder "/var/www/html" as the  DocumentRoot (not in apache2.conf nor in 000-default.conf). But if I run an info.php script in /var/www/html I got thie env DOCUMENT_ROOT = /var/www/html.

```
Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.html) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

.httacess file: (located in /var/www/html)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I checked that the server works, I can see the phpinfo() here http://loacalhost/info.php
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJJYC.png

Answer (score 0):

Well I did not realized that the mod_rewrite.c was not installed, that's why the .httacess fike was ignored :), now everything is ok.